# ProxyError coming while using simple code

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use `request.get` in python, but it is throwing error. I am using this very simple code:

```
import requests

x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com')
print(x.status_code)
```

However, this throws this error:

```
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='w3schools.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001ECB3E72040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))
```

Comment: It looks like you may have a proxy enabled in your system, You should check your settings to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code (prints `200` for me), but you may want to try to disable SSL verification:

```
x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com', verify=False)
```

Python is known for not trusting anything out there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it still didn't work.